# John Lawler's ELU answer links, by topic

Tags: discussion

This is more of an announcement than a question. But it's intended for Meta.

For [a class I'm giving](http://websites.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/ALLclass/Englishclass.html), I've recently made up links to my answers here,
on various grammatical topics. This list is on my web site at

- [http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/ELUanswerlist.html](http://websites.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/ELUanswerlist.html)

The individual topics covered, so far, are

1. [Relative clauses](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299%20relative%20clause)
2. [Negative Polarity](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299%20negative%20polarity)
3. [Cleft Sentences](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299%20cleft)
4. [Quantifier Float](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299%20quantifier%20float)
5. [Particle Shift](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299%20particle%20shift)
6. [*Whiz*-Deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299%20whiz%20deletion)
7. [Reflexivization](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299%20reflexivization)
8. [Conjunction Reduction](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299%20conjunction%20reduction)
9. [*There*-Insertion](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299%20there%20insertion)
10. [Passive](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299%20passive)
11. [Dative](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299%20dative)
12. [Extraposition](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299%20extraposition)

In addition, there's a [list of basic terms and concepts](http://websites.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/ALLclass/English1.pdf) of English phonetics and syntax
(two of the things not covered in most English classes).

There may be more, depending on demand.
As always, everyone is invited to make use of these.

Comment: Erm, in normal circumstances it would be a bit weird, but maybe it's apposite here. How about making your title more easily searchable. Perhaps "*John Lawler's ELU answer topic file*" or something thatwise? Also, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: This will be quite useful. How about a topic on non-finite clauses, for example when do participle verb phrases used as subjects or objects become non-finite clause or are they always so. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/516423/are-bare-present-participles-used-as-subject-or-objects-non-finite-clauses-if-n

Comment: Participles are always non-finite, and when they are verbs they form non-finite clauses.

Comment: It [that disclaimer](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/disclaimers.html) supposed to resemble the shape of a male reproductive organ? It seems to me a rather odd use of the align center..

Comment: @JJforTransparencyandMonica - It's more rocket-shaped, to help your understanding of the English Language ascend from the gutter to previously unknown heights. Or, turn it upside down, and it's pick-shaped to help you plumb the depths of the English language. If the human penis was really shaped that way, you (or any of us) would probably not be here. And to Dr. Lawler, from who(m) I've learned so much, thanks!

Comment: Here's a search for ["non-finite"](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299+non-finite); there are 10 hits. Enjoy.  As for the shape of that list, I found I could do it and therefore did. HTML is a very nice language.

Comment: @anongoodnurse potato, potáto, I've seen [rockets that were even more resembling](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/jeff-bezos-rocket-penis_n_7182914). As for the list itself, it is an interesting list though the answers are a bit spread over. :)

Comment: It's just a device to keep me from repeating myself yet again.

Comment: Thank you for this, @John Lawler. I am a relatively new user, but I have already noticed the depth of your knowledge and your always helpful attitude in sharing it. The tone of your comments, even when you correct misconceptions or language usage, always seems welcoming and encouraging. Yours is an excellent model to follow, and I hope that it will inspire anyone with years of experience on the site who is tempted by snarkiness to communicate in a collegial way instead.

Comment: I note in the news that Stack Exchange has been sold (!) for over a billion (!!) dollars. I'd thought my contributions were open to all here without charge, but I guess I'd better reconsider.